# Text classification with Tensorflow_Hub

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

I'm following this tutorial
https://medium.com/tensorflow/building-a-text-classification-model-with-tensorflow-hub-and-estimators-3169e7aa568 on how to build text classifier with TensorFlow HUB. I've modified it with my dataset which consists of two columns "post, tags". There are 8 tags.
When I run this script it gives me error: AttributeError: type object 'Reduction' has no attribute 'SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE'
I want to see if code works for me but i'm getting this error.
Code:

```
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_hub as hub
import json
import pickle
import urllib

from sklearn.preprocessing import MultiLabelBinarizer

print(tf.__version__)
data = pd.read_csv('dataset3.csv')
descriptions = data['post']
genres = data['tags']
train_size = int(len(descriptions) * .8)

train_descriptions = descriptions[:train_size].astype('str')
train_genres = genres[:train_size]

test_descriptions = descriptions[train_size:].astype('str')
test_genres = genres[train_size:]
description_embeddings = hub.text_embedding_column(
  "movie_descriptions", 
  module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2"
)
top_genres = ['n', 'a', 'g', 'o', 'i', 'u', 'r', 'v']
encoder = MultiLabelBinarizer()
encoder.fit_transform(train_genres)
train_encoded = encoder.transform(train_genres)
test_encoded = encoder.transform(test_genres)
num_classes = len(encoder.classes_)

# Print all possible genres and the labels for the first movie in our training dataset
print(encoder.classes_)
print(train_encoded[0])
description_embeddings = hub.text_embedding_column("descriptions", module_spec="https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/2", trainable=False)
multi_label_head = tf.contrib.estimator.multi_label_head(
    num_classes,
    loss_reduction=tf.losses.Reduction.SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE
)
features = {
  "descriptions": np.array(train_descriptions).astype(np.str)
}
labels = np.array(train_encoded).astype(np.int32)
train_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn(features, labels, shuffle=True, batch_size=32, num_epochs=25)
estimator = tf.contrib.estimator.DNNEstimator(
    head=multi_label_head,
    hidden_units=[64,10],
    feature_columns=[description_embeddings])
estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
eval_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({"descriptions": np.array(test_descriptions).astype(np.str)}, test_encoded.astype(np.int32), shuffle=False)
estimator.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn)
# Test our model on some raw description data
raw_test = [
    "Firma doo", # Documentary
    "Bočak 23", #Adventure
    "51250 Novi Vinodolski", # Comedy
]

# Generate predictions
predict_input_fn = tf.estimator.inputs.numpy_input_fn({"descriptions": np.array(raw_test).astype(np.str)}, shuffle=False)
results = estimator.predict(predict_input_fn)
# Display predictions
for movie_genres in results:
  top_2 = movie_genres['probabilities'].argsort()[-2:][::-1]
  for genre in top_2:
    text_genre = encoder.classes_[genre]
    print(text_genre + ': ' + str(round(movie_genres['probabilities'][genre] * 100, 2)) + '%')
  print('')
```

Comment: Which tutorial? please do not answer just edit your question. What is the shape of the test & train genre?

Comment: Dataset is like this (some address 15, a) or (name, n). Genre is single character in second column.

Comment: When I run this code on Colab it runs perfectly. Could the problem be with Python version. My version is 2.7

Comment: It has nothing to do with the error SUM_OVER_BATCH_SIZE because it defined in Reduction.

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example to make it easy for others to figure out the problem.

Comment: I've added link to dataset in text and modified code. This code now works on Colab but not locally.

Comment: Try to update your tensorflow to the latest version.